# Should we remove the "duplicate question" flag on this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

Question under consideration: [How to debug obfuscated JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932095/how-to-debug-obfuscated-javascript)

This question is marked as a duplicate of an earlier question ([How do you debug through a compressed javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835485/how-do-you-debug-through-a-compressed-javascript-file)). However, the newer question has a much more useful answer as the accepted answer. The older question's answers basically say "You can't. Don't do that," while the newer question has more useful tips. I think this is due to the nature of the two questions being very slightly different. In the older one, the developer is in control of the source, which gives them better options before deploying code. In the newer one, the developer is *not* in control of the source, which means they have to get more creative. I think the answer for the newer question is also applicable to the older question.

What kind of cleanup (if any) should be done in this scenario?

Comment: You can comment to ping @Louis (the gold badge holder who closed the later question) to re-open, explaining the scenario. Then vote to close the older one as a duplicate of the newer. In my experience, this usually works fine without specific Meta support. There is already enough general Meta support to close as duplicate of better Q&A combination regardless of age.

Comment: Also, you can visit the close vote review chat room, or potentially the javascript one, to explain the issue and possibly gather more close votes. As the 8yr old question may struggle to generate interest.

Comment: Another option not discussed so far is to merge the posts. I've not looked at either question here so I'm not necessarily recommending this, but it might be the right choice.

Comment: This looks like a good pair of candidates for a merge.

Comment: Is it so bad that a well-worded question/answer should be flagged as a duplicate of a poorly-worded QA that came first?   Is it hurting the site in some way?   Both come up in Google searches.   Not being rhetorical here, I honestly don't know enough about the site mechanics to know the answer to this question.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Unfortunately, yes. Users that aren't logged-in will never see the dupe-closed question: it silently redirects to the dupe target.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical case of:

- The new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932095/how-to-debug-obfuscated-javascript) has a far better wording than the [old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835485/how-do-you-debug-through-a-compressed-javascript-file)
- The new question includes example code, which make it easier to figure out what it is about, in the blink of an eye
- ... but still, it's the (good) new question which is closed as duplicate of the old (not so good) one!

I usually cannot do anything in such cases because I think I don't have enough rep, but if I could I would reverse the duplicate: mark the less-good-wording question as a dupliacte of the new good one.

Comment: You have more than 3k rep, so you *can* do something. In particular, you can leave comments, edit, and cast a reopen vote on the newer one, and cast a close vote on the old one if and when the new one is reopened.

Comment: You're right @NathanTuggy! I always thought "How to reverse the duplicate?" which seemed impossible, but the workflow you describe seems to work too :)

Comment: (`cast a close vote on the old one if and when the new one is reopened`: this is not very handy because you have to remember/bookmark the link, and come back a few days later to see if the new one is reopened. And in this case mark the old as duplicate... But at least it works, thanks!)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Also, in practice, the workflow you suggest is (in my experience) about 90% to 99% likely to fail at the "get the new one reopened" step, regardless of how good the reasons for reopening might be. The reopen review queue is so flooded with autoflagged crap that it's basically just training reviewers to click "Leave Closed" on everything except obvious audits (and the audits *are* pretty obvious). Now, if you replaced that step with "post a [reopen-pls] in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)", then it *might* actually work.